# Jquery trigger click then fill in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table row that when clicked should trigger a click event on page that opens a div.  once this div is open, i need #poId to be populated with given id.

```
    $('tr').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#purchase\\.exist').trigger('click');
            //What goes here?               
    });
```

the page that results from the click is:

```
  <input type='text' id='poId' name='poId'>
```

basically i need to know what i can use to fill poId with click automatically.  in layman's terms

```
$('tr').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        //Open page as a result of trigger
        //paste the variable id in the poId input              
});
```

Added fiddle:

This fiddle is completely stripped down but the idea is a user clicks on the word question. a table appears with two rows.  when a user click on the table row, the purchase div is opened and the input needs to be populated with the id of the tr clicked.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f94gh2z/)

I know there are other ways to do this without trigger, but opening the div actually entails a bunch of other things (ajax functions and such) before the div is opened, so just simply opening the purchase div wont work

Comment: Try making a working example in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), that way we can see how the row elements are being created.

Comment: @bart2puck your question is unclear.  Did you want to add content to a div, or navigate to a completely new page?

Comment: working on fiddle.       i have a menu on the left side,  this table is inside menu1 div.   when you click on tr,  it generates a click to menu to open menu2div.   inside menu2 div is an input with id of poId.

Answer (score 0):

To populate poId with the value of the ID of the tr that was clicked on (which I think is what you're asking):

```
 $('tr').click(function(){
        $("#poId").val(this.id);
        $('#purchase').trigger('click');
});
```

(I am assuming that "#purchase\.exist" was a typo of some sort?)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hide').hide();

  $('tr').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#poId').val(id);
    // the second argument is an array of parameters that will be passed to the function
    $('#purchase').trigger('click', [id]);
  });

  // the first argument of function `click` receives is the event, the next are the arguments passed from the trigger
  $('li').click(function(e, id) {
    var liID = $(this).attr('id');
    var div = $('#div_' + liID)
    div.show();
    div.find('input').val(id)

  });
});
```

```css
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id='purchase'>Purchase</li>
  <li id='question'>Question</li>
</ul>

<div id='div_purchase' class='hide'>
  <input type='text' id='poID' name='poID'>
</div>
<div id='div_question' class='hide'>
  <table id='myTable'>
    <tr id='12345'>
      <th>12345</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id='45678'>
      <th>45678</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```